# Symfony2: Using Doctrine outside controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm a bit of noob when it comes to OOP PHP, so please forgive me if I make this sound more complicated then it is.

Basically I am trying to clean up my controller as it's starting to get too cluttered.

I have my entities set up and I have also created a repository to add methods for some db queries to a sqlite database.

But now I also have to manipulate this data before outputting it, I've created a separate connector class that fetches additional info (from an XML web source) for each item being queried and then this gets added to the doctrine query data before being outputted.

I could manipulate this data in the repository but the data I am adding obviously doesn't originate from my entity. So I have therefore created a separate model class to add this data.

Please tell me if I'm on the right track.

In my entity repository I will have a custom method like this:

```
public function queryTop10All()
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager($this->em)
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('u.ratingkey, u.origTitle, u.origTitleEp, u.episode, u.season, u.year, u.xml, count(u.title) as playCount')
            ->from($this->class, 'u')
            ->groupBy('u.title')
            ->orderBy('playCount', 'desc')
            ->addOrderBy('u.ratingkey', 'desc')
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Now I created a new class in \Model\ChartsDataModel.php and I am injecting doctrine into it using a service and calling the custom method, getting the results and then adding the additional data from the web connector to it, like so:

```
namespace PWW\DataFactoryBundle\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use PWW\DataFactoryBundle\Connector\XMLExtractor;
use PWW\DataFactoryBundle\Connector\WebConnector;
use PWW\ContentBundle\Entity\Settings;

class ChartsDataModel {

    private $settings;
    private $repository;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->settings = new Settings();
        $this->repository = $this->settings->getGroupingCharts() ? 'PWWDataFactoryBundle:Grouped' : 'PWWDataFactoryBundle:Processed';
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getChartsTop10All()
    {
        $xmlExtractor = new XMLExtractor();
        $webConnector = new WebConnector();

        $results = $this->em->getRepository($this->repository)->queryTop10All();
        $xml = $xmlExtractor->unXmlArray($results);

        $outputArray = array();

        foreach($xml as $item) {
            $outputArray[] = array(
                "ratingKey" => $item['ratingkey'],
                "origTitle" => $item['origTitle'],
                "origTitleEp" => $item['origTitleEp'],
                "playCount" => $item['playCount'],
                "episode" => $item['episode'],
                "season" => $item['season'],
                "year" => $item['year'],
                "type" => $item['media']['type'],
                "parent" => $webConnector->getMetaData($webConnector->getMetaDataParentKey($item['ratingkey'])),
                "metadata" => $webConnector->getMetaData($item['ratingkey'])
            );
        }

        return $outputArray;
    }
}
```

**The xmlExtractor class is used to pull out certain xml fields stored in a database field as a raw xml dump.**

My config.yml:

```
services:
    pww.datafactorybundle.model.charts_data_model:
        class: PWW\DataFactoryBundle\Model\ChartsDataModel
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
```

Then in my controller, I just instantiate a new ChartsDataModel and call the method like so:

```
namespace PWW\ContentBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
...
use PWW\DataFactoryBundle\Model\ChartsDataModel;

    public function chartsAction()
    {

        $charts = new ChartsDataModel($this->getDoctrine()->getManager());
        $top10Array = $charts->getChartsTop10All();

        return $this->render('PWWContentBundle:Default:charts.html.twig', array('page' => 'charts', 'top10' => $top10Array));
    }
```

I just want to know if I am doing this correctly and is there a better way of doing this (or right way)?

I'm also very new to Symfony and still getting my head around it. I just don't want to get into bad habits so I'm trying to do things right from the start.

I hope I explained this well enough :)

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Just detected two things that are in the top of my head.

## 1 If you define the service like:

> ```
> services:
> pww.datafactorybundle.model.charts_data_model:
>     class: PWW\DataFactoryBundle\Model\ChartsDataModel
>     arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
> ```

Then you can inject it in the controller like described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html), so you keep the service arguments out of the Controller:

```
    public function chartsAction()
{
 $myservice = $this->get('pww.datafactorybundle.model.charts_data_model');
 $top10Array = $myservice->getChartsTop10All();
}
```

Secondly, I would not put this standard queries in the Model, I think is better to keep the models clean with their setters, getters and put this custom queries elsewhere like in a service that will handle all related Chart queries and you can instance from anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the input, really appreciate it. I'll make those changes. I'm still a bit confused as what a "Model" really represents in Symfony. From what I've read models in Symfony are really all up to you. Does it really matter if I put this is a Model class or a Service class?